# Components won't appear

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to output these components but they won't appear. I can't figure out what I did wrong.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Buttons extends JApplet {
  Container con;
  JPanel form;
  JButton oneB, twoB, threeB;
  public void init() {
    con = new Container();
    form = new JPanel();
    form.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    oneB = new JButton("1B");
    form.add(oneB);
    twoB = new JButton("2B");
    form.add(twoB);
    threeB = new JButton("3B");
    form.add(threeB);
    con.add(form);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 5):

You never added `con` to anything

In fact, it's not really needed, just add `form` to the applet...

```
  public void init() {
    form = new JPanel();
    form.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    oneB = new JButton("1B");
    form.add(oneB);
    twoB = new JButton("2B");
    form.add(twoB);
    threeB = new JButton("3B");
    form.add(threeB);
    add(form);
  }
```

If you're just learning, I would highly encourage you NOT to use applets, they have their own issues which can make learning a real pain.  Instead, try starting with window based components, like `JFrame`

Comment: oh thankyou i forgot con = getContentPane(); thats why i was getting nothing

sadly this is fro a final so i have to learn applets 

thankyou again for your help

Comment: As of Java 5, you no longer need to use `getContentPane`, `add` will automatically redirect to the contentPane